# Android Recycler layouts not inflating properly why

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I use an android recyclerview to inflate three layouts as shown in my code but the footer is not being inflated properly hence hides some data of the listview layout. Where is the problem with my code since I want the listview layout to be displayed as the last layout in the recyclerview adapter.

```
package com.news254.inception.newsapp;

 import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Newspaper extends AppCompatActivity {
 Toolbar mtoolbar;
  String TITLES[] = {"Newspaper","Gossip","Entertainment","Sports","International","About","Exit"};

int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.newspaper,R.drawable.gossip,R.drawable.entertainment,R.drawable.sports,R.drawable.international,R.drawable.about,R.drawable.exit};

//Similarly we Create a String Resource for the name and email in the header     
  view
//And we also create a int resource for profile picture in the header view
 Boolean isDrawerOpen =true;


private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the               

Toolbar Object

 RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring      
RecyclerView
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter     
For Recycler View
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout    
 Manager as a linear layout manager
 DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring     
 DrawerLayout

  ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
  ImageView       
Nation,Standard,Capital,Nairobian,BusinessDaily,EastAfrican,Star,Mwakilishi,Citizen;
 String nation  = "http://www.nation.co.ke";
String standard = "http://www.standardmedia.co.ke";
String star = "http://www.the-star.co.ke";
String  nairobian = "http://www.sde.co.ke/m/thenairobian";
 String eastafrican = "http://www.theeastafrican.co.ke";
String businessdaily = "http://www.businessdailyafrica.com";
String mwakilishi = "http://www.mwakilishi.com";
String capital  = "http://www.capitalfm.co.ke";
String citizen = "http://www.theweeklycitizen.co.ke";

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);


mtoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);


mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
// And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
// and header view profile picture

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager
Nation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nation);
Nation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",nation);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
Standard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.standard);
Standard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",standard);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
     Star = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.star);
      Star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Entertainment.class);
        p.putExtra("site",star);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
Capital = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capital);
Capital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",capital);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
Nairobian = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nairobian);
Nairobian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",nairobian);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
Citizen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.citizen);
Citizen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",citizen);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
EastAfrican = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eastafrican);
EastAfrican.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",eastafrican);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
BusinessDaily = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.businessdaily);
BusinessDaily.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",businessdaily);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});
Mwakilishi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mwakilishi);
Mwakilishi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent p = new Intent(Newspaper.this,Browser.class);
        p.putExtra("site",mwakilishi);
        startActivity(p);

    }
});

Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
        // open I am not going to put anything here)
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
    }

  /*  @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        if(slideOffset >.55 && !isDrawerOpen)
        {
            onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            isDrawerOpen=true;
        }
        else if (slideOffset <.45 && isDrawerOpen)
        {
            onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            isDrawerOpen = false;
        }
       // super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }*/
}; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

// / Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle


getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

}

   @Override
     public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

 @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      }

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu);
return true;
}

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
 if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
{
    return true;
}
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 } }

  package com.news254.inception.newsapp;

   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

   /**
     * Created by hp1 on 28-12-2014.
      */
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;  // Declaring Variable to     
 Understand which View is being worked on
 // IF the view under inflation and population is header or Item
  private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
   private static final int TYPE_HEADER= 0;

  private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles 
   Value from MainActivity.java
       private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons       
          resource value from MainActivity.java
   private int mfooter[];
  private String mtitleFoot[];
  int Holderid;

      // Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
       // ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to   
            recycle them

   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
int Holderid;

TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;
ImageView about;
TextView name;



public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
    super(itemView);


    // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

    if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
        Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
    }
   else if(ViewType == TYPE_FOOTER){


        about = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
       // Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
        Holderid =2;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
    }
    else if(ViewType == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        Holderid =0;

      }
  }


  }



           MyAdapter(String Titles[],int Icons[]){ // MyAdapter Constructor 
            with titles and icons parameter
               // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the   
                 main activity as we
               mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
               mIcons = Icons;
                //here we assign those passed values to the values 
                   we declared here
                   //in adapter



    }



//Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when   
 the ViewHolder is
   //Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the 
      viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
   // if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
    // and pass it to the view holder

    @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int    
               viewType) {

if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

    ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

    return vhItem; // Returning the created object

    //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

}
else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false); //Inflating the layout

    ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v, viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

    return vhHeader; //returning the object created
}

else if  (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer, parent, false); //Inflating the layout

    ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v, viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

    return vhHeader; //returning the object created
}
    return null;

        }

   //Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is 
      needed to be displayed, here the int position
     // Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed 
        and the holder id of the holder object tell us
       // which view type is being created 1 for item row
     @Override
         public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int 
         position) {
if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
    // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
    holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position-2]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position-2]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
}
else if (holder.Holderid ==2){





     holder.about.setImageResource(mIcons[position]);          // Similarly we set the resources for header view
        holder.name.setText(mNavTitles[position]);



}
else if (holder.Holderid ==0){



}
   }

   // This method returns the number of items present in the list
         @Override
         public int getItemCount() {

return mNavTitles.length+2;

// the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
}


 // Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
 @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {


if (position == 0) {
    return TYPE_HEADER;
}
 else if (position ==2) {
    return TYPE_FOOTER ;
}
else  {
    return TYPE_ITEM;
     }
 }

  private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
  return position == 0;
}


   }
```

Comment: Your code setting the content to the footer view seems to be commented out.

Comment: Sorry,, I uncommented them out and still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**Change  this**

```
   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if (position == 0) {
       return TYPE_HEADER;
      }
     else if (position ==2) {
      return TYPE_FOOTER ;
     }
     else  {
     return TYPE_ITEM;
     }
   }
```

**To**

```
   @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0){
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }

    else if((mNavTitles.length+ 1) == position){
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }else{
         return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}
```